# Query: Response does not match configured parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

i am getting response error please any one try to solve my problem. i am trying to solve that but i didn't solve this. please help me. 
thanks in advance

```
$scope.init = {};
var Call = $resource('../api/Home', {}, { query: { method: 'POST', isArray: false} });
        $scope.init = function () {
            //alert("hi");
            $scope.selected = "";
            var x = $('#txtSearch').val();
            var _ReqObj = new Object();
            _ReqObj.id = x;
            _ReqObj.Meth = "GJ";
            Call.query({}, _ReqObj,
             function (response) {
                 alert(response);
                 alert(_ReqObj);
                 if (response == '') {
                     // alert('no data');

                     window.location.replace("index.html");
                 }
                 else {
                     //$scope.click = response;
                     $scope.init = response;

                 }
             },
                        function (error) {
                            window.location.replace("index.html");

                        }
                     );
        };
```

Comment: did you check this link? https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=object&p2=array&p3=POST&p4=..Fapi%2FHome

Comment: Could you please change the title of the question? The error link does not help. Could you click on the error link in your dev console in the browser and then copy the text from the angular-page? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says: "Expected response to contain an object but got an array"

this means: Your request (Call.query) does expect a single object (you are setting isArray: false). But the server sends an array. So the server is not sending what the function expects!

There is some hints I want to give you:

1. Why are you using query? A query is normally used to get an array from the server, not a single object. Why are you using query at all?
2. Do you really want a single object or do you want a list of objects?
3. What is the server sending? Open the development console in your browser (ctr+alt+I in Chrome) and click on the Network tab. Click on the request (../api/Home) and check the response from the server. You should see the json objects or arrays the server sent as a response to your request.

Comment: thanks for asking me question. this question was very helpful to me. i got the exact response.